# Rails .last clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Hello I have a rails ap that runs *devise*... has a **customer** model. I have a **after_create** on customer that starts with  `@customer = Customer.last`   I'm looking for clarification on .last If more then one user at a time creates a *customer* will the .last be accurate or is there a chance the value can be the other users object?

Do I need to specify some sort of @customer = Customer.last.where(user_id = current_user.id) for example?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after_create is an instance method of the class so it has reference to the object as `self`.

So you can do...

```
@customer = self
```